# Can I run Cloud Automation (azure or aws) for web apps in background and performing other tasks on same device?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, automation, cloud, rpa

- Hi all, **my goal is to automate some tests for a web app and in parallel do some other staff manually (like writing code locally or research or writing reports) and  don't collide with it**.
  I used softwares like Ginger, Power Automate Desktop but i'm not able to do anything else until the automation is done otherwise it's interrupted. The RPA works as if it is me. It takes control of the computer it's running on.
  I was thinking of moving on cloud automation by using Azure or AWS in order to run the automation initiating from my device and in parallel to do other staff.

**Tried**:  Ginger, Power Automate Desktop but i'm not able to do anything else until the automation is done otherwise it's interrupted. The RPA works as if it is me. It takes control of the computer it's running on.

**Expectation**: automation of tests AND do other staff without colliding on same device with the result to do as much work as possible.